# Two approaches to the product of two sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $t_n=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ be convergent real sequences/sums with limits $s=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $t=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$. Since the limit of the product of two convergent real sequences is exactly the product of the respective limits, we know:
$$ (\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k) \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n \cdot t_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k,l=1}^n a_k \cdot b_l  $$
If we have respective absolute convergent sums $s_n$ and $t_n$, we know the Cauchy Product:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^l a_k \cdot b_{l+1-k} =(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k) \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k) $$
In this case, it seems like:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{l=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^l a_k \cdot b_{l+1-k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k,l=1}^n a_k \cdot b_l $$

**My question:** Is this true? And if so, why is the first intuitive approach to the product of sums not seen in standard textbooks?

Edit: I know that the Cauchy product has some more properties and more meaning, but that's not what I'm talking about. I want to talk about the product of sums with a new perspective, namely from a standpoint concerned about sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \cdot b_{n+1-k} =(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k) \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k)$$

The correct expression is:
$$(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k) \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k) := \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n+1-k}$$

Why? Because this is *defining* the Cauchy Product, which is being denoted by "$\cdot$".

In your version, you used "$\cdot$" in the same equation with two different meanings. In "$a_k \cdot b_{n+1-k}$", it means ordinary multiplication of the two real or complex values. But in $(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k) \cdot (\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k)$ is denoting the Cauchy Product, which is a convolution of two series - a different operation entirely.

And that is the answer to your question. These are diffent operations. Your third equation is false. In your first equation, you are just talking about the multiplication of two numbers, and how multiplication interacts with limits. This *is* discussed in textbooks, which is why you were able to reproduce it here. But because it was so intuitive, you didn't really notice it.

But the Cauchy Product is something different. It is not just multiplying two series together. It is a type of summation that one encounters somewhat regularly, so it gets a special name and some study of its properties.

You will see many other cases of operations denoted by the same symbol. There are just too many possible operations out there to give unique symbolry to each of them. You wouldn't be able to remember them all. You determine which operation is meant by context.

Comment: But from the standpoint of sequences (and not sums) the third equation should be true, right? @Paul Since they have the same limit, namely the product of the *values* of the sums.

Comment: Also, the Cauchy product is in fact also a multiplication of two real numbers, namely $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$.

Comment: @Rino - NO! It is not! The Cauchy Product is a *different thing* than the multiplicative product of the two series, and that is why your third equation is false. Consider the series $1 + 2 + 3 + 0 + 0 + \dots$. The multiplicative product of this series with itself is just $36$. The Cauchy product is $0$, because for $n \ge 6$, the non-zero elements are all multiplied by $0$. The Cauchy product is *not* a tool for calculating the multiplicative product. It is a different "product" altogether.

Comment: I've looked it up and the Cauchy product can be used for infinite series, but not for finite series when the product of the limits is concerned.

Comment: And @Paul I think you're misunderstanding me... the third equation is an equation of limits of sequences, not series

Comment: (1) "can be used for infinite series" is weasel wording. You are assuming that it is equal to a product of two infinite series, and your sources made no such claim. (2) "$1+2+3$" is finite, but "$1+2+3+0+0+\ldots$" is infinite. (3) No I did not misunderstand you. You got the third equation from the first two, which you mistakenly thought were calculating the same thing. (4) If you think that having trailing zeros is why my example doesn't work, and somehow without them it will suddenly start working, try the calculation for $a_k = b_k = 2^{-k}$ In fact, try it for any example.